# Solidity return enum in library

Tags: solidity, library, enum

```
library MyLib {
    enum MyEnum {
        A, B
    }

    function f() public pure returns (MyEnum){
        return MyEnum.A;
    }
}
```

I want to return the enum in library.
It is deployed as well, but revert on contract call.
this is the error message.
{
"error": "Failed to decode output: Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="MyLib.MyEnum", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)"
}

Help me..

Comment: It works well on contract instead of library. but i want to make it library.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas each element in Enum is integer, you can come back from `f()` function uint type and cast Enum element in uint. You can see this example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library MyLib {
    enum MyEnum {
        A, B
    }

    function f() public pure returns (uint){
        // MyEnum.A = 0;
        // MyEnum.B = 1;
        return uint(MyEnum.A);
    }
}
```